# "bundle install" causes Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError on each gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, openssl, rvm, bundler

When calling

```
rails new project
```

The process progresses until I hit bundle install. At that point:

```
identical  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert handshake failure (https://d2chzxaqi4y7f8.cloudfront.net/gems/rake-0.9.2.2.gem)
An error occured while installing rake (0.9.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '0.9.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I can install the gem manually with gem install and launch rails new again, and the error repeats for the next gem. I end up installing manually every single gem.

I use rvm 1.13.0 single user.

Comment: if you are using RVM you should read `rvm requirements`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have OpenSSL installed?  You don't mention your OS, but on Ubunutu (or other Debian-based distros) you do:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Failing that, try http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: Thank you. The "failing that" option saved the day.

Comment: :ssl_verify_mode: 0 in ~/.gemrc from "Failing that" solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: I followed the "Failing that" option and looked for Windows instructions. There was a link for how to fix the problem if you have RailsInstaller. I didn't have RailsInstaller, just Ruby, so I followed the "manual" instructions and changed RailsInstaller to Ruby200-x64 and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```